# (Newton-)Mechanical geometry, "equigradiental" surfaces, how can we calculate them?

Tags: analysis, reference-request, soft-question, physics, classical-mechanics

Consider a Newtonian mechanics gravity field with a center of mass $m$ at position ${\bf v}$ like so:

$$F({\bf v}) = \sum_{k} G\cdot m\cdot m_k\cdot \frac{({\bf v-v_k})}{\|({\bf v-v_k})\|^3}$$

, assuming we have a set of mass centers $\bf v_k$ each having mass $m_k$

or we can rewrite using ${\bf F} = m{\bf a}$:

$${\bf a}({\bf v}) = \sum_{k} G\cdot m_k\cdot \frac{({\bf v-v_k})}{\|({\bf v-v_k})\|^3}$$

It is easy to imagine if we have two equally large masses $m_1=m_2$, we will have a plane of locally highest potential energy in "the middle" of these points. By continuity this surface should slowly morph into some other shape than a plane as we slowly continously alter the relation between $m_1$ and $m_2$.

Can we calculate some algebraic expression for this curve? Like a level-set of some function?

Comment: It's the level set $a(\mathbf v) = 0$.

Comment: Clearly can't be. In example, any point at rest in plane will accelerate towards mid point where a=0 but whole plane is not.

Comment: Force is the gradient of potential energy. Where potential energy is maximized, that gradient will be $0$, and therefore the magnitude of acceleration will be $0$. Admittedly, this also picks up minima and stationary points, but certainly all maxima of potential energy are in that set.

Comment: You are probably correct and I was not careful enough when posing the problem. Maybe I should try an algebraic description of what the properties of this surface I have in mind has.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Ok, maybe this formulation is better at expressing what I was thinking about : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3303370/name-of-equiacceleratory-surface-in-a-force-field

Comment: Well, that was why I made a comment, even though it seemed to answer the question. I thought it likely you hadn't overlooked the obvious, but actually meant something different than I was understanding.