# Name of "equiacceleratory" surface in a force field in physics?

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, analysis, physics, classical-mechanics

I started thinking about a situation in physics a while back and I once reached a situation where a force field was shaped so that there existed a surface $\mathcal S$ which had the property

$${\bf F}({\bf v}) \cdot {{\bf \hat n}({\bf v})} = 0, \hspace{1cm} \forall {\bf v} \in \mathcal S$$

Where ${\bf \hat n}({\bf v})$ was normal vector to this plane in the actual point.

The easiest way to realize such must exist is to take two equally massive planets, their forcefield will be symmetric and in the middle there shall be a plane which has the property that for any point in this plane, it accelerates stuff towards the center of mass of the whole system (which lies in the plane). So we could for example create orbits in this plane which are around an invisible point in the middle between the planets.

What would we call a surface like this? I suppose it has some name in physics?

(I throw in algebra tag because I suspect maybe we can view action of gravitation on a small object in this surface as a group in some sense. At least in plane case it is obvious that any motion starting in the surface will stay so we have a set with closure and should be possible to prove other group axioms as well.)

Comment: Looks related to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_point perhaps?

Comment: @BenedictW.J.Irwin It is related. A Lagrangian point would be a local point of attraction in such a surface.

Comment: The surface you want is tangent to the force field at all points. Perhaps, a "flow"? But it has been too long since I looked at flows to recall if they require more than just tangency.

Comment: A "flat direction in the potential"? $\nabla V \cdot \hat{\mathbf{n}}=0$

Comment: The term "equipotential surface" comes to mind, as in this article : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equipotential

Comment: @MarcBogaerts no its not equipotential. Because unique maximum is at infinity which surface gets arbitrary close to, but minimum is obviously unique somewhere on a line between centers of mass.